# Configure multiple servletcontainers/servlets with spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I want to load two servlet containers with embedded tomcat configuration on different ports with Spring Boot.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It should be simple: just create as many `ApplicationContexts` of type `EmbeddedWebApplicationContext` as you need and give them each an `EmbeddedServletContainerFactory` with a different port. Example [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/af75dd0e4090db706afe4a7bd40d226b413e01a0/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.java#L158) where the two contexts are parent and child, but that's not a necessary part of the setup.

Comment: It would be nice to have a proper example in the answer because links may be dead at some time.