# SpringBoot configure two different server ports

Tags: spring-boot

I have a spring boot application which serves the following on `8080`

```
REST      => /api
vaadin    => /admin
static content => /web
```

Currently these three just have separate paths but it would be nice to make the static content only available on port `80`.

I know, that a external load balancer like nginx can handle this, but if it is possible, I would like to avoid adding a LB.

Comment: This is one application, or three separate?

Comment: It's probably easier to have multiple applications https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22973523/spring-boot-multiple-web-applications (look at the comments by Dave Syer), otherwise you might have to run multiple Tomcat connectors http://stackoverflow.com/a/41218348/1915448. But you'll have to find out how that you can limit each connector to a specific path.

Comment: @RandallFlagg This is one application.

Comment: @g00glen00b hm, if I use multiple applications I can also just use a LB.

Comment: @guenhter sure, I was just adding that to the comment in case you really want to avoid a reverse proxy/LB/... .