# Ignore context-path for specific endpoint in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have setup the property `server.servlet.context-path=/xyz` in the application.properties file so all my endpoint have a prefix of /xyz. Now, I want to create an endpoint that should not have /xyz as the prefix(as an exceptional scenario). How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Technically it is not possible because spring boot has only one `DispatcherServlet` which is a front controller, if you want two different paths then you can use `@RequestMapping` annotation on two different controllers`

Still of you want two different `context-paths` then you should have two `DispatcherServlet's`

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to configure two `DispatcherServlets` in the same app?

Comment: i believe perfect place for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29096511/using-multiple-dispatcher-servlets-web-contexts-with-spring-boot