# 2 @RestControllers with different configurations

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Is it possible to have two different **@RestControllers** that **use different** **MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter** in Springboot ? ... or is the MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter common for all @RestController in a spring boot application ?

Basically, the goal would be to use a different MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter containing a different Jackson ObjectMapper that uses a Jackson MixIn to rename(in the Json) the id to priceId in the 2nd Controller.

What a call to the first controller would do :

http://localhost:8080/controller1/price

{ id: "id", description: "Description" }

What a call to the second controller would do :

http://localhost:8080/controller2/price

{ priceId: "id", description: "Description" }

Regards

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class EndpointsApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(EndpointsApplication.class, args);
}

@Data // Lombok
@AllArgsConstructor
class Price {
    String id;
    String description;
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/controller1")
class PriceController1 {

    @GetMapping(value = "/price")
    public Price getPrice() {
        return new Price("id", "Description");
    }
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/controller2")
class PriceController2 {

    @GetMapping(value = "/price")
    public Price getPrice() {
        return new Price("id", "Description");
    }
}

}
```

GitHub:

https://github.com/fdlessard/SpringBootEndpoints

Comment: Please have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34728814/spring-boot-with-two-mvc-configurations this post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` is common for all controller annotated with `@RestController`, nevertheless there are ways around this. A common solution is wrapping the result returned by your controller into a marker class and using a custom `MessageConverter` [(Example implementation used by Spring Hateoas)](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/blob/3f6cb3269ca779ba6f7b1b128ed7e195d89bff9a/src/main/java/org/springframework/hateoas/server/mvc/TypeConstrainedMappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java) and/or using a custom response media type.

Sample usage of `TypeConstrainedMappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` where `ResourceSupport` is the marker class.

```
MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter halConverter = 
    new TypeConstrainedMappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(ResourceSupport.class);
halConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(HAL_JSON));
halConverter.setObjectMapper(halObjectMapper);
```

You can find a working example based on your code here:
https://github.com/AndreasKl/SpringBootEndpoints

Instead of using a `PropertyNamingStrategy` a custom serializer can be used for your `Price` transfer object.