# Using multiple webapps on the same port with spring boot

Tags: java, spring, servlets, spring-boot

Is there a possibility to configure several webapps in a spring boot with embedded tomcat in a way that:

- Each webapp has its own context url
- Each webapp has it own ServletContext
- Each webapp is loaded in a separate classloader (like it would be deployed on standalone tomcat https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html)
- Webapp is not bundled into war

I saw already:

[Using multiple dispatcher servlets / web contexts with spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29096511/using-multiple-dispatcher-servlets-web-contexts-with-spring-boot) - as far as I understand we actuall have here one webapp with one ServletContext and classloader.

[Configure multiple servletcontainers/servlets with spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21630820/configure-multiple-servletcontainers-servlets-with-spring-boot) - here different ports are used for webapps and I would prefer to have it on one port

Comment: Would this answer your question

http://www.davidtanzer.net/running_multiple_spring_boot_apps_in_the_same_jvm

Comment: Sounds like what you need is a web server sitting in front of your webapps.

Comment: @Vhshal Jumani: In solution from http://www.davidtanzer.net/running_multiple_spring_boot_apps_in_the_same_jvm different ports must be used and I would prefer to have one port for all webapps

Answer (score 0):

There is a possible solution over on Softare Engineering Exchange: [How to wrap multiple Spring Boot applications in a single one](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/329158/how-to-wrap-multiple-spring-boot-applications-in-a-single-one)

(I'm aware this is an ancient question, but I was looking for an answer to it today.)